# how to fix 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable' in flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wsgi

I want to create a web service using Python. 
The service contents are as follows.

1. Receive music files from users
2. Analyze the received file and create a new music file. (The function implementation has already been completed using the python library.)
3. Output the newly created music file to the user.

The main goal is to analyze the music file and create a new one, and input and output the music file for this purpose is a secondary function. So I have no knowledge of creating web services and need help to implement this feature. I went to the internet and implemented it to some extent, but I get an error that I don't know why.

I Upload the code for `app.py` and `__init__.py`. I also uploaded the structure of the directory. It looks like something needs to be fixed to use the functions inside the controller. I've been searching the internet and YouTube for more than twelve hours, but I don't really know. I created a class named `NoteConvertor` and `MarcovMatrix` in the controller directory.

It runs until I go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and receive a file. Then I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\K\git\flask\gp\app.py", line 24, in wav_transform

sr, data = scipy.io.wavfile('static/file1.wav')

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

-gp
|----controller
|        MarcovMatrix.py
|        MatrixBuilder.py
|        NoteConvertor.py
|----static
|        style.css
|----templates
|        index.html
|        upload.html
|        wavplay.html
|----__init__.py
|----app.py
```

**app.py**

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import pysynth as ps      
from scipy.io import wavfile  

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route("/upload")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wav_transform():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(f'static/file1.wav')
        sr, data = scipy.io.wavfile('static/file1.wav')

        empty_notes = controller.NoteConvertor(data)
        notes = empty_notes.convertor()
        song = sum(notes, [])

        matrix = controller.MarcovMatrix(song)
        start_note = ['e4', 4]

        random_song = []
        for i in range(0, 100):
                start_note = matrix.next_note(start_note)
                random_song.append(start_note)

        ps.make_wav(random_song, fn='static/random.wav')

        return render_template('wavplay.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)


__init__.py
from gp.controller import MarcovMatrix
from gp.controller import MatrixBuilder
from gp.controller import NoteConvertor
```

I would like to tell you how to use the functions written in python (inside the controller) inside the flask.

I would be very grateful if you would like to know how to do what I want to implement. Please understand this question because learning the basics of the web is not my main goal.

Comment: Please also show the `import`s in app.py

Comment: I coreected.  I'd appreciate to see you again.

Comment: The OP makes two very basic Python mistakes are are well-covered by many other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an import issue. You have the choice of either

```
import scipy
...
sr, data = scipy.io.wavfile('static/file1.wav')
```

or

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
...
sr, data = wavfile('static/file1.wav')
```

Comment: Oh, I solved this problem. This was a minor mistake. Thank you very much. But a new problem came up with the following error: 'NameError: name 'controller' is not defined' This is where I'm really hard. How can I use the python class I created in the controller?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in `gp/controller`?

Comment: No... Should I create __init__.py in the gp/controller as well? If so, what should be written? Doesn't it work with the __init__.py alone in the gp in the code above?

Comment: Python looks for the presence of an `__init__.py` (which can be empty) to determine if a directory corresponds to a module.  See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: The NameEroor problem has been solved.  Thank you so much for your continued interest in my problem.. but, this time I get this error:AttributeError: module 'controller' has no attribute 'NoteConvertor'. Why am I getting this error? I certainly wrote NoteConvertor.py in gp / controller..